# What books should I use for learning Algebra?

Tags: reference-request, education

I am only $13$ years old and I get A's in pre-algebra $8.$ I want to start learning Algebra so I can get prepared for next year and maybe even get into an advanced math class. So, what books are the best for learning Algebra?

Comment: use the mathematics books by springer

Comment: We hope you enjoy [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home) :-)